# Are there exceptions to the rule that requirements should be atomic?

Tags: specifications, requirements, atomic, convention

I'm reviewing a requirements spec where some of the requirements include the word "and" or sometimes even a list of required functionality.

Am mostly thinking these should be broken up but this does have the downside of making a long document even longer and even less readable - which in practice may mean its intended audience ends up skimming over it or only reading sections rather than absorbing the whole thing.

However, there are some requirements where it seems a bit silly to break them up. E.g: there are a lot of get/set operations, which always go together - it seems a bit overkill to always break them up into "The user shall be able to get...", "The user shall be able to set..." Other examples are enable/disable, validation lists, supported platforms/browsers etc.

Just wondering if anyone has had similar thoughts and whether it might sometimes be OK to break the rule of atomicity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that you do not have to break up the requirements, as long as you uniquely identify them. E.g. "[REQ1] The user should be able to [a] set ... and [b] get ..." In this way you keep the document readable and also keep the possibility of separately tracing the atomic parts.